# Akka.NET logger not sending logs to Application Insights

Tags: azure, akka, azure-application-insights, akka.net, akka-monitoring

I've set up Application Insights as a logging provider in Akka.NET and set up `Akka.Monitoring` to record various custom metrics (such as counting messages received and timing processing duration). This works great.

But the logs I generate using Akka.NET's logger do not get sent to Application Insights:

```
var logger = Logging.GetLogger(Context);
logger.Info($"Please send me to Azure!");
```

I would expect to see it in the Traces section on Application Insights along with my other .NET Core log items.  These logs, however, do appear in my runtime output, which I assume is stdout.

Application Insights is configured using `Akka.Monitoring.ApplicationInsights` like so:

```
ActorMonitoringExtension.RegisterMonitor(system, new ActorAppInsightsMonitor(instrumentationKey));
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Peter's answer, I had to implement a custom logger for this:

```
public class ApplicationInsightsLogger
        : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

    private readonly IDictionary<LogLevel, SeverityLevel> _logLevelMap = new Dictionary<LogLevel, SeverityLevel>()
    {
        { LogLevel.DebugLevel, SeverityLevel.Verbose },
        { LogLevel.InfoLevel, SeverityLevel.Information },
        { LogLevel.WarningLevel, SeverityLevel.Warning },
        { LogLevel.ErrorLevel, SeverityLevel.Error },
    };

    public ApplicationInsightsLogger()
    {
        Receive<LogEvent>(message => this.Log(message.LogLevel(), message));
        Receive<InitializeLogger>(_ => Sender.Tell(new LoggerInitialized()));
    }

    private void Log(LogLevel level, LogEvent item)
    {
        if (!_logLevelMap.ContainsKey(level))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{level} log level isn't handled.");
        }

        SeverityLevel severity = _logLevelMap[level];

        _telemetry.TrackTrace(new TraceTelemetry()
        {
            Message = item.Message.ToString(),
            SeverityLevel = severity,
            Timestamp = item.Timestamp,
            Properties = { { "Source", item.LogSource } }
        });

        if (item is Error)
        {
            _telemetry.TrackException(new ExceptionTelemetry()
            {
                Message = item.Message.ToString(),
                SeverityLevel = severity,
                Timestamp = item.Timestamp,
                Properties = { { "Source", item.LogSource } },
                Exception = (item as Error).Cause
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library to do that or did you write your own logic to send it to app insights? How is app insights configured?

Comment: @PeterBons See my edit.  I'm using `Akka.Monitoring.ApplicationInsights`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick scan reveals that the only calls to App Insights are `TrackMetrics` calls. To send log messages like `logger.Info($"Please send me to Azure!");` one would expect a call to  `TrackTrace`. So I suppose the library is only useful to track metrics, not messages. This is further confirmed by the fact that the package description reads:

> Akka.Monitoring is an ActorSystem extension for Akka.NET that exposes a pluggable layer for **reporting performance metrics** from actors back to a monitoring system suc ....

Anyway, the [documentation](https://getakka.net/articles/utilities/logging.html) does not indicate there is an Application Insights logger available.

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented a custom logger in the end.  Works now.